# SSRS PDF Progress AX 2012 R3?

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

Is it possible to get the exact progress status when exporting SSRS PDF from AX using x++?

I'm currently struggling to try to find a way to track the exact progress of a report that AX users run in batch, which in the end is saved to a folder as a PDF document.

I'd like to get somehow the progress of this report generation and the PDF exporting so I can update the batch task or even give some feedback about the process to them.

Comment: Is your batch process exporting a single report or multiple reports? Batch progress percentage is really the number of batch tasks in a batch job. So if you are exporting multiple reports, then you should make your batch header spin up a task for each report, then the batch job progress will show 10% if 1/10 tasks is complete.

Comment: The problem is bigger when it's more than one. I realized that when the batch job runs in parallel, that batch task progress is not displayed properly.

Comment: What I'm saying is you need to create a custom batch header class that will aggregate all of the batch `jobs` into batch `tasks`. Or are you saying you would like to see progress of a single report run in batch?

Comment: I have already a batch header class running, and its progress is displayed correctly, but batch tasks progress is not. For example, when I post a sales invoice with late selection flagged, which is a multithread process, only the main batch shows me the progress precisely, the batch tasks show only the progress 0 and/or 100. I can't see the actual progress of those tasks.

Comment: I think the batch tasks themselves need to implement the progress, which many do not.

Answer (score 2):

Is kind of tricky, The time it takes will depend on many factors. machine resources, complexity of the report, total records exported by report, etc.

Maybe what you can do is a progress bar that takes into account the total amount of PDF that you are going to export and for each pass update the progress bar ones that are being exported.

***Something like that:***

```
static void Stackoverflow(Args _args)
{
    #AviFiles
    SysOperationProgress progress = new SysOperationProgress();
    int i, total;

    ;

    progress.setCaption("Exports PDF");
    progress.setAnimation(#AviUpdate);
    total = 90000; //Your total of PDF documento to export
    progress.setTotal(total); 

    for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) //Your loop to create PDF
    {
        //Your code to create PDF in folder
        progress.setText(strfmt("PDF generation %1 of %2", i, total));
        progress.setCount(i, 1);
        //Your code to create PDF in folder END
    }        
}
```

[image]